# java String variables not setting

Tags: java, string, null

This is a much simplified version of a class file I'm working on, I've just used these classes to show my problem.

```
public class Test {
    private String string1 = null;
    private String string2 = null;

    private void setString(String s) {
        s = "hello";
    }

    private void set() {
        setString(string1);
        setString(string2);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(string1);
        System.out.println(string2);
    }

    public void initialise() {
        set();
        print();
    }  
}

public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.initialise();
    }
}
```

Anyway, basically, after this the two string variables are still null. What causes this problem? and how can I get around it? (Still learning the fundamentals of java - if that's relevant).

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Lion This is OP's demonstration of the problem.

Comment: No need to be a douche, but in the much bigger class file, something like this is needed.

Comment: @Andrew Strange, compiles just fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that [Java is pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference), so your setString method does not do anything. To change the value of `string1`, you need to have `string1 = xxxx;` somewhere in your code. For example:

```
private void set() {
    string1 = getDefaultString();
    string2 = getDefaultString();
}

private String getDefaultString() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because a String is immutable, any change you make inside the method will be local to that method.

```
private void setString(String s) {
   s = "hello";
}
```

`s` can't be changed.

I can think of two options.

**Option 1**

Make `s` an instance variable (field) and change your method.

public class Test {
    private String string1 = null;
    private String string2 = null;
    private String s;

```
private void setString(String s) {
    this.s = "hello";
}
```

**Option 2**

Pass in a `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` instead of `String`.

Comment: This only explains part of the story; the other part is that `s` is a reference to a `String` object, and that *can* be modified.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth `s` is a *copy* of the reference to a `String` object. So, even if you were to modify the reference by re-assigning, the original String wouldn't be changed (that's considering String wasn't immutable in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of "s" not string1 or string2

try something like.

```
private void setString(String s) {
        string1 = "hello";
        string2 = "world";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By making this assignation

```
 s = "hello";
```

weare creating a new object. It will have a different memory address than the one passed with `setString(string1);`

We would need to change the object received at

```
 private void setString(StringBuilder  s) { ... }
```

instead of creating a new one. We need to use exactly the same object we were passed in this method. Can't create a new one, as the caller method wouldn't notice (parameters in Java are never output parameters).

As Java's String is **inmutable**, we can't change its content: just create a new String object.

As @adarshr pointed out, we can use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`, which are mutable, and change their content. But we can't just replace `String` with `StringBuilder`in you code. We have to make sure that:

1. The `StringBuilder` is initialized before being passed to `setString()`.
2. The `StringBuilder` is not created again inside `setString()` (we are using the same one we were passed).

So, replacing this in your code should work:

```
private StringBuilder string1 = new StringBuilder();
private StringBuilder string2 = new StringBuilder();

private void setString(StringBuilder  s) {
    s.append("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you misunderstand of java parameter passing, try `public void setString1(String s) {         string1 = s;     }`

Comment: oh, yes, change method to public.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to initialize the values of `string1` and `string2` to? The two member variables start out being `null`.

If I were to treat `Test` class as a POJO (plain old Java object), I would add getter/setter methods as follows:

```
public class Test {

  private String string1;
  private String string2;

  public String getString1() {
    return this.string1;
  }

  public String getString2() {
    return this.string2;
  }

  public void setString1(String s) {
    this.string1 = s;
  }

  public void setString2(String s) {
    this.string2 = s;
  }

  /*
   * Additional methods
   */
  public void set() {

    setString1("hello");
    setString2("world");
  }

  public void print() {

    System.out.println(this.string1);
    System.out.println(this.string2);
  }

  public void initialize() {

    set();
    print();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in his requirement that points to the need for setters. Why would you add some?

Comment: I was just trying to illustrate a common practice with POJOs in general. Those methods are not specifically part of the answer.

Comment: I understand - I was just pointing out that the general approach should be to make your objects as immutable as possible, unless you **have to** make them mutable, not the other way round.

Answer (score -2):

ur application is assigning the hello word in parameter s..but the variable s is a parameter type thats y the reflection of s will be in setString() method block...not anywhere else...use instance variable or static variable to see the reflection of ur assignment.

Comment: Please use proper English, not "ur" and "y".